# How to run these set of sh commands in bat file?

Tags: batch-file, sh

I need to run this sh commands. First, the command will be this one

```
keytool -importcert -file myfile.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Aliasname"

Enter keystore password:

Re-enter new password:

Trust this certificate? [no]:
```

I need to run this commands automatically, And when the first command is successful. It asks for a password. I need to enter it automatically. and finally yes. 
How to do that using .bat file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If keytool is compliant with standard input, you can use:

```
(
echo your_password
echo your_password
echo y
)|keytool -importcert -file myfile.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Aliasname"
```