# Batch script automatically send enter command?

Tags: java, batch-file

I have the batch script below. And it is prompting for a source keystore password which requires the enter key to be pressed. Is it possible when it prompts for the password the batch file automatically simulates the enter key? I cant specify the src password as it does not work.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\keytool.exe" -importkeystore -srckeystore ".\trusted.certs" -destkeystore "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs" -deststorepass changeit
Enter source keystore password:
```

Comment: No you won't be able to simulates the Enter key, as it is a user action and your reading is probably done through a `Scanner`

Comment: user1342164, you've now asked four questions in less than a day, all relating to exactly the same task, and you appear not to have actively engaged with responders such that your task is resolved. Please make an effort to help us support you, and please do not spam the forum with multiple half questions when one fully detailed question would have stood a greater chance of attracting a positive solution. Also in between your multiple questions, the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48439384/6738015) was accepted, which may be of some use to you.

Comment: Try `echo. | "C:\...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows Scripting Host to send keys to the current window. Create the file SendEnter.vbs with the following contents.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.sendKeys "{Enter}"
```

Then in your batch file, call it before running keytool:

```
cscript //nologo SendEnter.vbs
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\keytool.exe" -importkeystore -srckeystore ".\trusted.certs" -destkeystore "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs" -deststorepass changeit
```